# The description under the Articles tab uses plural form when there’s only one article

Tags: bug, status-completed, collectives, articles, plurals

There's currently one article in the Google Cloud Collective. However, that fact is described on the [Articles tab](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud?tab=articles) using plural form:

> Browse 1 article**s** that **are** relevant to the Google Cloud Collective.

It should either be changed to *"1 article that is relevant..."* or show the same message that is displayed when there are no articles:

> Browse articles that are relevant to the [...] Collective.

Just to be clear, this is not something that happens once in the lifetime of the collective. There's the ["Your articles" sub-tab](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud?tab=articles&subtab=yourarticles), which is likely to have one article for many users (at least, recognized members and employees, for now) and it's not yet clear exactly what will be shown on the "Newest" sub-tab.

Comment: Wow, people _really_ hate pluralization bug reports for some reason :-D

Comment: Or they just don't think it's a priority.

Comment: @41686d6564 Exactly like _Cerbrus_ said: That's too minor for bug reports here.

Comment: frankly speaking, folks, I am not sure I like how we treat pluralization bug reports - it's still a bug. Yes, it's minor, but do we really think SE cares one bit if we report minor ones or major ones? Features and bugs for the public platform haven't been a priority for them in ages as well, so it's not like we delay the "real" FRs.

Comment: This is low-priority, sure, but it's also low-effort to fix.  Where else are people _supposed_ to report minor bugs, if not on Meta?

Comment: https://mobile.twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105

Comment: @CrisLuengo [That meme is officially deprecated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63791/348196) :)

Comment: @41686d6564: I know it’s no longer official SO policy. But you can’t deprecate a meme.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been fixed (for all tabs), which you can see in the [GitLab Collective's Articles page](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/gitlab?tab=articles) (since they currently have only one article):

[image: screenshot showing singular "article" text]

Thanks for reporting.  Bugs are bugs, even if they're "small" bugs.